# Need help completing this regular expression that captures relative paths in HTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a specific case (prefer not to use Cheerio or jsdom) and need a flexible regular expression that will find all relative paths for images—even those with invalid markup. I have two issues which can be seen at http://www.regexr.com/3bkil.

- Not capture the beginning single and double quotes. "'
- Not capture those that are missing a less than symbol. <

Here is what I have so far...

```
(?!(\<\s*img [^\>]*src\s*=\s*))[\"\']\s*[\w\.\-\/]+(\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif))(?=(.(\"|\')|(\"|\')))
```

Almost there. Here are the test cases.

```
TO MATCH:
<img src="images/vendor.png" alt="" > <img src="images/vendor.gif" class="box-bg-image" alt="" >
<img src="images/vendor-dp-20141009-flatware.jpg" class="box-bg-image" alt="" >
<img src="images/vendor-flatware.jpeg" class="box" alt="" >
<img src='images/vendor-flatware.jpeg' class="box" >
<img alt="" src= 'images/vendor-flatware.jpeg' alt="" >
<img src=' images/vendor-flatware.jpg' alt="" >
<img src=' images/vendor-flatware.gif' alt="" >
<img src=' images/vendor-flatware.png ' alt="" >
<img src='../silverware.png' alt="" >
<img class="box" src='images/vendor-watch.png' alt="" >
<img src=" images/vendor-flatware.jpeg " alt="" >
< img  src="images/vendor-flatware.jpeg " alt="" >
< img  src="images/vendor-flatware.jpeg " alt="" >
<img src="vendor.gif" alt="">


NOT TO MATCH:
<img src="http://thirdpartycdn.com/image.jpg">
<img src='http://thirdpartycdn.com/image.png'>
<img src="http://thirdpartycdn.com/image.gif" class="box-bg-image" alt="">
img src="images/vendor-flatware.jpeg "
<img src="images/vendorpng" alt="" >
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should parse the string into HTML, then process the `src` attribute.

Comment: @torazaburo In the browser, yes. But I'm in Node.js and don't have a window or document object to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Javascript doesn't have lookbehinds, I would go with this:

```
\<\s*img[^>]*src\s*=\s*["']([^"':]+?\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif))
```

and use the content of the first capture group.

Your negative look-ahead `(?!(\<\s*img [^\>]*src\s*=\s*)` is useless here. (Remove it, you will see it gives the same result, because you are checking that it isn't there, and as you don't have `"<img...`, it's always true).

I removed the final check for ["'] because since your extensions are well defined, there isn't much of a point.

Comment: No valid reason. I worked over OP's expression and forgot to remove the escape character.

Comment: Short and easy to read, I like this one the best. Final results can be found at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lemezinoqe/1/edit?js,output) and [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oM7tH8/2). I gave up on my search for an overarching regular expression after reading this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454).

Comment: Good news is, I don't need to use Cheerio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`(?:'|")([^"':]*?\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)[^'"]*(?=[^<]+?>))`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/yT7fW8/1)

But.. why not a `DOM Parser`?

Comment: What happens if you have a picture file name in another type of tag/attribute?

Comment: So, there will be a problem, but which tag? Sorry my english

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
((?:<\s*img[^>]+?src=\s*["']))(?!https?:\/\/)([^'"]*?\..*?)(?=["'].*?>)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xS1bJ0/1)
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tuqigatila/edit?js,output)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Thanks, i didn't really see it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out regex101.com! I think I'm going to use that tool from now on. I ran your regex through jsbin (http://jsbin.com/nosofalace/1/edit?js,output) and it removed '<img src='. Isn't there anything else that can be done to further capture the relative path?

Comment: @Aaron check my updated answer for jsbin and updated regex to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This one is work

```
(?:<\s*img[^>]+src\s*=['"\s]+)((?:[\w\d-\/.]+|[\w\d-]+)\.\w+)
```

You can get image paths via variable `$1`

**Strategy**

My strategy is separating your target pattern into two types

1. Image path that consist of `/` e.g. `images/vendor-flatware.png`,
2. Image path without `/` e.g. `vendor-flatware.png`.

**Regex Explanation**

`(?:<\s*img[^>]+src\s*=['"\s]+)`: Find start of image tag until open symbols of file path which here dynamically match by `['"\s]+` roughly means either `'` or `"` or `space` with any combination,

`[\w\d-\/.]+`: Match first type of file path (contain `\`),

`[\w\d-]+`: Match second type of file path (do not contain `\`),

`\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif)`: Match file extention.

**Additional**

In case that you want to use it with replace function try this

```
(<\s*img[^>]+src\s*=['"\s]+)([\w\d-\/.]+\.\w+|[\w\d-]+\.\w+)
```

Where first `(...)` is captured to `$1` and the second `(...)` is captured to `$2`.

If you test this regex on http://jsbin.com/xebedunoki/edit?js,output you can test to use replace function like this

```
var newstr = strVar.replace(reg, "$1XXX");
```

Here, you will see that all paths will be replaced by `xxx`

Comment: I have to test this further but I think I was able to accomplish the task with your regex: http://jsbin.com/jozarufela/1/edit?js,output. But, I'm very curious what the $1 does?

Comment: `$1` just stand for message like `< img ...="` and when you want to replace it you suppose to concat it back as well otherwise you will see that all `< img ...="` are removed.

Comment: In my regex, the first `(...)` is captured to `$1`, the second `(...)` is captured to `$2`.